# Netbeans outputs error for first php debug trial and then refuses successive debugging requests

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans-7

First time to write\debug php code, no idea why is it that hard !!!!

When I first start `Netbeans` I only want to debug an opened script, within a project, so I start debugging, an application specific error is shown in the `Output` window (i.e. SQL syntax error) so I can deal with that error but afterwards the actual problem arises.

- If I add a breakpoint and start debugging again, it won't start and I'm perfectly sure it doesn't reach the breakpoint.
- So I restarted `Netbeans`. Had my breakpoints saved, started debugging, and it didn't even honor the breakpoints !

Regards

Comment: What is the error shown in the Output window?  That kind of information is helpful to identifying the problem

Comment: The error shown for the first time is an app-specific error (SQL query syntax error) so it's not related to netbeans. Thanks for the reply